# Override date format attribute of csvhelper before writing the records

Tags: c#, csvhelper, .net-7.0, csvhelper.excel.core

Using CsvHelper through CsvHelper.Excel.Core (hence stuck at version 27.2.7) I am not able to override the date format when generating the excel file.

Format is defined through an attribute (CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes)

```
    [Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Then I generate first a CSV file then an Excel version.

1. CSV with US date format

   ```
      using (var writer = new ExcelWriter(destCsv, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        {
                            writer.WriteHeader<MyFormat>();
                            writer.NextRecord();
                            writer.WriteRecords(MyRecordsInMyFormat);
                        }
   ```

This work well a date is formatted as in the attribute

2. Excel with GB date format

   ```
   using (var writer = new ExcelWriter(destXlsx, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        {
                            writer.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yy" }; 
                            writer.WriteHeader<MyFormat>();
                            writer.NextRecord();
                            writer.WriteRecords(MyRecordsInMyFormat);
                        }
   ```

I have also tried

```
                            writer.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(new TypeConverterOptions {Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yy" }});
```

but the dates always stays in format defined in the attribute at the beginning (US format in my case)

[Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

what is this not overriden? An easy workaround would by to duplicate the mapping and use an attribute in GB format for my excel output, but it's poor practice and on top of that I have many files with complex mapping making the whole thing impracticable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Format` attribute sets the `TypeConverterOption` for the `Date` property.  Any individually set option will override the general `TypeConverterOptionsCache`.  You can see that here. `Date1` maintains its attribute formatting, whereas `Date2` gets the `TypeConverterOptionsCache` formatting.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var MyRecordsInMyFormat = new List<MyFormat>
    {
        new MyFormat { Id = 1, Date1 = new DateTime(2022,11,23), Date2 = new DateTime(2022,11,24)}
    };

    // TypeConverterOption on Date1 overrides TypeConverterOptionsCache on the context
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yy" } });
        writer.WriteRecords(MyRecordsInMyFormat);
    }
}

public class MyFormat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

Your best solution is going to be to not use the `Format` attribute and always set the `DateTime` formatting through `TypeConverterOptionsCache`. If that is not possible, you will have to manually override the `TypeConverterOption` on `Date1`

```cs
void Main()
{
    var MyRecordsInMyFormat = new List<MyFormat>
    {
        new MyFormat { Id = 1, Date1 = new DateTime(2022,11,23), Date2 = new DateTime(2022,11,24)}
    };

    // Have to individually override the Date1 TypeConverterOption
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var map = new DefaultClassMap<MyFormat>();
        map.AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        map.Map(m => m.Date1).TypeConverterOption.Format("dd/MM/yy");
        writer.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
        
        writer.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yy" } });
        writer.WriteRecords(MyRecordsInMyFormat);
    }
}

public class MyFormat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ok thank your for explaining difference between TypeConverterOption /TypeConverterOptionsCache!  Option1 is ok, a bit painful to update all the existing code, but having a class deriving from csv helper can avoid specifying format everywher. Not sure to understand why in option2 you would also do TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions? Anyway with complex mapping this seems impracticable. Ideally I would have liked to have the ExcelWriter ignore the format attribute

Comment: If you had to manually update all `DateTime` variables then you wouldn't need `TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions`. It would only be helpful to catch those that didn't have the `Format` attribute, like `Date2` in my example.